# In Unity 2021.3.29, why is a total volumeDepth of just 100 for global texture arrays slowing down the entire game?

Tags: unity, rendertexture, compute-shader

In order to apply the metaball effect on a pixel in the Dest RenderTexture, I need the minimum distance to every game object that is involved in generating the metaball effect for that pixel. This means I need a non unique value from a signed distance field texture for that game object at the point of that pixel. Here is the compute shader method relevant to generating the metaball pixel color:

```
[numthreads(THREAD_GROUP_WIDTH, THREAD_GROUP_WIDTH,1)]
void CSMainFirst (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    //float4 srcPixel = max(ColorTextureArray.Load(uint3(id.xy, 0)), ColorTextureArray.Load(uint3(id.xy, 1)));
    //float4 srcPixel = ColorTextureArray.Load(uint3(id.xy, 1));
    float4 srcPixel = Src[id.xy];
    //1. Case when pixel that is currently being processed is initial seed(part of GO) and don't need to be metaballed.
    if(any(srcPixel.rgba > float4(0,0,0,0).rgba)) {
        float4 displayPixel = float4(0,0,0,0);

        uint visibleGameObjectCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < GameObjectListCount; i++) {
            float4 colorAtDepth = ColorTextureArray.Load(uint3(id.xy, i));
            if(any(colorAtDepth.rgba > float4(0,0,0,0).rgba)) {
                displayPixel += colorAtDepth / GameObjectListCount;
                visibleGameObjectCount++;
            }
        }
        displayPixel *= (GameObjectListCount / visibleGameObjectCount);

        if (all(Dest[id.xy].rgba <= float4(0,0,0,0).rgba)) {
            Dest[id.xy] = displayPixel;
        }
        return;
    }
    //2. Case when pixel being processed is outside game object
    else {
    //Metaball effect
        //variables
        float closestDistanceProduct = 0;
        int SDFcounter = 0;
        int DistancePrimeCounter = 0;
        uint visibleGameObjectCount = 0;
        
        //Fetch blur color
        float metaballCoefficient = 0;
        float metaballCoefficientOneUp = 0;
        float finalMetaballCoefficient = 0;
        float finalMetaballCoefficientOneUp = 0;
        float metaballBlendingFactor = 0.055f; //0.025f = waterslime
        float totalDistance = 0;
        float4 metaballColor = float4(0,0,0,0);

        //This loop must be done for every game object in Src
        for(int i = 0; i < GameObjectListCount; i++) {
            //Current closest distance
            float currentClosestDistance = SDFTextureArray.Load(uint3(id.xy, i));

            // int currentDeltaX = (int)-DeltaXTextureArray.Load(uint3(id.xy, i));
            // int currentDeltaY = (int)-DeltaYTextureArray.Load(uint3(id.xy, i));

            //uint Modified Delta
            // uint unsignedModifiedDeltaX = abs(currentDeltaX);
            // uint unsignedModifiedDeltaY = abs(currentDeltaY);

            //GCD
            // int gcd = (int)binaryGCD(unsignedModifiedDeltaX, unsignedModifiedDeltaY);
            // int minimumDeltaX = currentDeltaX / (gcd * 10);
            // int minimumDeltaY = currentDeltaY / (gcd * 10);
            //Current closest distance one up
            // float currentClosestDistanceOneUp = SDFTextureArray.Load(uint3(uint2(id.x + minimumDeltaX, id.y + minimumDeltaY), i));

            if(currentClosestDistance > 0) {
                // if(currentClosestDistance > 24) {
                //     DistancePrimeCounter++;
                // }
                //Increment counter for visible SDF pixels at that id.xy
                SDFcounter++;

                //Update total distance
                totalDistance += currentClosestDistance;

                //Metaball coefficient update
                metaballCoefficient += exp2(-metaballBlendingFactor * currentClosestDistance);
            }
        }
        //Compute weighted metaball color
        for(int j = 0; j < GameObjectListCount; j++) {
            //(totalDistance - currentGameObjectDistance - ((SDFcounter * totalDistance - 2 * totalDistance) / SDFcounter)) / totalDistance
            float currentClosestDistance = SDFTextureArray.Load(uint3(id.xy, j));
            float4 currentClosestColor = ColorTextureArrayBeta.Load(uint3(id.xy, j));
            if(currentClosestDistance > 0) {
                float weight = (totalDistance - currentClosestDistance - ((SDFcounter * totalDistance - 2 * totalDistance) / SDFcounter)) / totalDistance;
                metaballColor += currentClosestColor * weight;
            }
        }
        finalMetaballCoefficient = -log2(metaballCoefficient) / metaballBlendingFactor;

        //Metaball effect
        //&& SDFcounter > 1
        if(finalMetaballCoefficient < 0 && SDFcounter > 1) {
            //Write to MetaballEdgeTex
            //MetaballEdgeTex[id.xy] = float4(1,0,0,1);
            Dest[id.xy] = metaballColor;
            MetaballEdgeTex[id.xy] = float4(1,0,0,1);

            // if(DistancePrimeCounter > 1) {
            //     MetaballEdgeTex[id.xy] = float4(0,0,1,1);
            // }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

So far, the volumeDepth of SDFTextureArray has been set to the number of instantiated game objects since that way, I can make sure that there are no overlaps between generated SDF textures. With 3 other global texture arrays I'm using, just 25 game objects leads to a total volumeDepth of 100.

Am I forgetting to do some important optimization step or is it normal that having a total of 100+ textures(total volumeDepth of 100+) large enough to slow down the entire game for a device with 8GB RAM? I truly did not think modern computers were feeble enough to not even be able to process 100 textures of dimension: 2778x1284, but this is the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: 2778x1284 @ 24 bit color is ~10.7 MB. Multiply that by 100 and your budget for those textures alone is now 1GB which seems like a noticeable %. But rather than speculate, you should profile the code - that's generally the first step in diagnosing and addressing performance issues.

Comment: The memory size of the textures probably has less impact on its own than the number of compute cycles spent visiting/modifying their texels, and the bandwidth use of shunting that data in and out of cache potentially multiple times per frame.